# Find adjacent entries for a javascript Map?

Tags: javascript

Given

```
var myMap = new Map()
myMap.set("alpha", "first")
myMap.set("beta", "second")
myMap.set("charlie", "third")
myMap.set("delta", "fourth")
myMap.set("echo", "fifth")
myMap.set("foxtrot", "sixth")
```

Starting from a given key...

```
myMap.get("charlie") //=> "third"
```

... how would I get the values for the surrounding keys?

```
// pseudo code
myMap.get("charlie").prev() //=> "second"
myMap.get("charlie").next() //=> "fourth"
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this while iterating over `myMap`:

```
var valuesICareAbout = [];

myMap.forEach(function(value, key, map) {
  valuesICareAbout.push({
    callSign: key,
    callValue: value,
    nextCallValue: map.get(key).next(), // pseudo code
    prevCallValue: map.get(key).prev()  // pseudo code
  });
});
```

---

In my actual use case, the keys of the Map are DOM nodes, and I need the siblings in order to calculate position offsets. It is expected that the `prev` value for the first node in the Map will be `null` and that the `next` value for the last node in the Map will be `null`.

That make sense?

Comment: So you are cloning DOM tree in a JS Map. Make sense? My first though was absolutly no. You can walk the DOM siblings with node.nextElementSibling and node.previousElementSibling.

Comment: `.get()` just returns the value, it doesn't contain any information about where it is in the map. You can't use `.next()` or `.prev()` on the result.

Comment: @torazaburo: they are, insertion order.

Comment: @Félix The values in the map are DOM nodes taken from [React refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html), so in this case, it's not trivial to work with the DOM directly. Also, the nodes themselves are not adjacent to each other in the DOM, only in the collection.

Comment: @Barmar I realize what `.get()` does; as I denoted in my question, the invocations for `.next()` and `.prev()` were pseudo code meant to further illustrate my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply iterating over the keys of the map as array?

```
var keys = Array.from(map.keys());
keys.forEach(function(key, i, keys) {
    var current = map.get(key);
    var previous = map.get(keys[i-1]);
    var next = map.get(keys[i+1]);
    // ...
});
```

(obviously have to account for first and last element here)

If this is only for internal code, you could also think about extending the existing Map class with your own `forEach` implementation which passes the previous and next value to the callback.

Comment: Hmm, seems like `Map` is currently supported natively in Chrome, whereas `Array.from` is not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Yep, has to be polyfilled or you have to create the array another way.